# Android Out of memory in change wallpaper in Galaxy Note 3

Tags: android

My simple code can change android wallpaper successfully but, on Galaxy Note 3 (4.4.2) I get an `OutOfMemoryError` and my app crashes.

```
Thread thread4 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        height = metrics.heightPixels;
        width = metrics.widthPixels;
        mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), mFullSizeIds[position]);
        bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBitmap, width, height, false);
        wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(SingleViewActivity.this);
        wallpaperManager.setWallpaperOffsetSteps(1, 1);
        wallpaperManager.suggestDesiredDimensions(width, height);
        try {
            wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
            HANDLER.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SingleViewActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                    startActivity(intent);
                    Toast.makeText(SingleViewActivity.this, R.string.choose, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    SingleViewActivity.this.finish();
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
                }
            });

        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
thread4.start();
```

On other android versions and other phones, my code works fine

Logcat:

```
04-12 21:56:26.466: E/dalvikvm-heap(7621): Out of memory on a 36864016-byte allocation.
04-12 21:56:26.476: E/AndroidRuntime(7621): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-12 21:56:26.476: E/AndroidRuntime(7621): Process: com.allbaloo.app.cartoony_wallpaper, PID: 7621
04-12 21:56:26.476: E/AndroidRuntime(7621): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** Try to use

```
bitmap.recycle();
```

to release memory

**2)** Try to reduce image quality using:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 2;
final Bitmap bitmap = tmapFactory.decodeFile(mediaFile.getPath(), options);
```

Answer (score 0):

> The `OutOfMemory` error comes when there is no enough space available
>   in Heap memory of your process.

For this, reasons may be `Memory leaking, large drawables used` etc. You should check logcat logs with `tag : dalvikvm` while you get the OOM error. This will give you hint how your heap is being used

The last workaround is to make your process heap more space by declaring `android:largeHeap="true"` in Manifest but this will make GC to complete longer and this results in pauses, sluggishness in your application